# Any way to prove that the gradient of f(x, y) is in fact the vector defined component-wise by the partial derivatives of f?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

So in a lot of math that I do, I find that unless I have some intuition or deep understanding of a concept, I won't get very far with just memorization alone. Our textbook introduced the gradient to us but didn't do a very good job of explaining why it's defined as $<f_x(x, y) , f_y(x, y)>$.

I do want to note that I don't know a lot of complex math, and I don't do well with abstract symbols and/or terminology. Could someone please kindly help me prove the gradient vector's definition?

Comment: You can't "prove" a definition. It is what it is. Period. You could nevertheless prove (or prove not) that a definition *makes sense* in regards of something else. Not this case, though.

Comment: You don't prove a definition...maybe you mean to ask for the motivation behind the definition?

Comment: But how did people decide "it is what it is"? It seems a bit circular to me to just take the definition for granted and then use it to "prove" other concepts (e.g. the directional derivative) that depend on it...

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, that would be nice. Where did it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the derivative is to approximate a function by a linear (actually affine) approximation of the form
$f(x,y) \approx f(x_0,y_0) + f_x(x_0,y_0) (x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0) (y-y_0)$. We can
write this as
$f(x,y) \approx f(x_0,y_0) + (f_x(x_0,y_0),f_y(x_0,y_0)) \bullet (x-x_0, y-y_0) $.

That is, the difference $f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)$ can be approximated by the
inner product of the vector $(f_x(x_0,y_0),f_y(x_0,y_0)) $ and the
perturbation $(x-x_0, y-y_0) $. The vector $(f_x(x_0,y_0),f_y(x_0,y_0)) $
is called the gradient.